# Is there any way to get current transaction id in SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transaction

I want to get current transaction id to log something in another process. The code is actually run in .net, but in SQL Server it will be similar to the following pseudo code:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    <GET CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID>

COMMIT TRAN
```

It's an old system which can only be run under SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

You could try...

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_current_transaction
```

Or more specifically for your purpose.

```
DECLARE @CurrentTran BIGINT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET @CurrentTran = (
    SELECT transaction_id FROM sys.dm_tran_current_transaction
)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-current-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) lists it as working on **all** supported versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

There are some DMVs (Dynamic Management View) in SQL Server that you can track and get useful information about request or running query in Database. Here is an example:

```
Select request_id, s.session_id, transaction_id, host_name, login_time, program_name, login_name, nt_user_name,
    text as QueryText
    From sys.dm_exec_sessions s
    Inner Join sys.dm_exec_requests r on r.session_id = s.session_id
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle)
    Where is_user_process = 1
```